# What is best practice for check on radio buttons

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a checkout page which have 2 radio buttons.

Company and Private

Private is checked by default, if click on company it shows a span. But if i reload the browser company will remain checked, but the span is not shown.

How to "combine" all this logic the best way?

i need to "check" on page load which one is checked + i need to check when there's a change to the radio set - can i combine that somehow, so i end up with just one function?

```
//Check if company is set 
if ($("#check-acceptd").is(":checked")) {
        $("#Name").hide(); 
        } 
    else
        {
         $("#Name").show();  
        }
    });

<span>Private</span>
<input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radioCustomerType" id="radioPrivate" />
<span>Company</span>
<input type="radio" name="radioCustomerType" id="RadioCompany" />

<span id="Name">testing...</span>
```

// UPDATE

I have tried to do it like this, but it's not working as expected. When it has been "fired"

```
function checkCustomerType(){
        if( this.checked ){
            $("#Name").hide(); 
        } else {
             $("#Name").show();  
        }
    }
    $('#RadioPrivate, #RadioCompany').change(checkCustomerType);
    checkCustomerType();
```

// A sollution, but there must be a better way, imagine i had just 3 radio buttons, then it would require much more validation.

```
function checkCustomerType(){
        if ($("#RadioPrivate").is(":checked")) 
        {
            $("#Name").hide(); 
        } else {
             $("#Name").show();  
        }
    }
    $('#RadioPrivate, #RadioCompany').click(checkCustomerType);
    checkCustomerType();
```

Comment: What is `#check-acceptd`?

Comment: if you want the radio checked to remain when page refreshed you have to use jquery.cookie plugin or some backend.

Comment: The #check-acceptd was a copy paste error.